# How to set the asp.menu.selectedvalue

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu

After a postback I have a function that first clears the menu items then dynamically rebinds the items from a list coming from the database..The Problem is the menu.selectedvalue would clear, the question is, how will I force the asp menu to have a selectedvalue? I tried using this code..

```
TabMenu.SelectedValue = ViewState["Tab"].ToString();
```

However it failed, it says Property or indexer 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.SelectedValue' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to digg into specific `Items` element:

```
TabMenu.Items[2].Selected = true;
```

Comment: hi, what if I dont know its index, like in my example i have stored the selectedvalue in the the viewstate,im using the selectedvalue since the index might get changed since my menu dynamically populates every time there is a new list added on the database.

Comment: After rebind via DataSource, you need to run some code to 'translate' (simple search for example :)) ViewState['Tab'] index to new index, then use this index to select the item . Consider using session or cache object to store menu data and regenerate only when it changes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this ( provided your itemvalue is always there ) :

```
TabMenu.Items.AsQueryable<MenuItem>().First(m => m.Value == ViewState["Tab"].ToString()).Selected = true;
```

Hope this helps